# Does FFMPEG have a "guard" against clipping?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, signal-processing, sox

SoX has a flag for automatic gain control with the --guard flag. This helps prevent clipping during file conversion (i.e. resampling, bit depth conversion, mp3 to wave, etc). Does ffmpeg have anything similar?

It seems like an intuitive and common sense option to include; however, I can't find it. How come?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg` has two options built-in:

1. [loudnorm](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#loudnorm): simple audio normalization
2. [dynaudnorm](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#dynaudnorm): dynamic normalization that evens out quiet and loud sections

It is worth mentioning a Python tool built on top of `ffmpeg` called [ffmpeg-normalize](https://github.com/slhck/ffmpeg-normalize). Why consider using it? As a design principle, `ffmpeg` does not allow for two passes of a filter, and only after the first pass you know the max audio power. `ffmpeg-normalize` applies two passes, achieving more accurate and linear normalization. It's not suitable for all applications, so be sure to check out the README.

Comment: Thanks. How could I use either of these to guard against clipping without specifying a target loudness? I don't want to change the audio file loudness. I'm looking to resample a batch of audio files, and I'd like to avoid clipping while doing so.